# How to run Dockerfile or docker-compose file from automation suite

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, dockerfile, ui-automation

I am creating an automation framework using `selenium` and my entry point in execution is creating containers of different db types, load them with database dumps and then start with tests.

I have one simple and might be a foolish question 
If I create a `docker-compose` file which creates the above mentioned container and generally we do `docker-compose` up command to run the docker compose file.

But can I control the `docker-compose/Dockerfile` when the execution is going on, like

Test starts from `TestNG -> Before` scripts execute to run the `docker-compose` file and create containers.

how can I control that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following options:

1- use ansible to deploy for you, you can write a play book with the steps
advantages: scaling, will manage everything for you, you can add notifications, but requires managing ansible itself and learning it.

2- use a shell script that will start things in order start the containers (or however you want the order to be) then start the TestNG, cheap and dirty solution.